# Database not updating between tests in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a create test followed by an update, however on the second test I'm unable to find the object created in the first test. I've realised that this is because the object is not added to the DB until after both tests have run. Does anyone know why this is? And how I can run a create test, followed by an update test that uses the object created in the create test?

```
from unittest import TestCase

class QuantsTests(TestCase):
     def setUp(self):
          self.factory = RequestFactory()

     def test_create_object(self):
          object = Object()
          object.name = "123456789"
          object.save()

     def test_update_object(self):
          Object.objects.filter(name="123456789")

Error: object.models.Model.DoesNotExist: Object matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Please show us your `main` function too.

Answer (score 0):

Each test is run in its own environment: before each test, the state of the system is resetted (including the database) and the setup() function is executed. This is done explicitly to make sure that the execution of one test does not influence the results of other tests.

If all your tests need the same objects in the database, you can move the code that adds those objects in the setup() function. Otherwise, each test should begin by adding to the database all the objects it needs. An intermediate solution would be creating some functions that add some objects to the database, so you won't need to write the same exact code in all the tests that require certain conditions in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Django test's reset after each test method.. So your flow currently is

```
QuantsTests -> SetUp -> create_object -> Rollback
QuantsTests -> SetUp -> update_object -> Rollback
```

You could use `subTests` and a single method instead, which is usually what I do when testing similar things

```py
class QuantsTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()

        def test_object(self):
            created = False

    with self.subTest('Create'):
        object = Object()
        object.name = "123456789"
        object.save()
        created = True

    if created:
        # No point of running + failing this one if the previous one failed.
        #   hence the check
        with self.subTest('Update'):
            Object.objects.filter(name="123456789")
```

---

##### Note:

Normal python unittest **do not** rollback after each method. Just something to remember

Comment: Strangely this didn't work for me, it seemed as though the rollback still happened between subtests. I ended up getting around this by calling the create test within the update. It's not the most efficient way as I end up running a test twice but will be fine for now.

The subtest is super useful though, I didn't know about it and it's really helped take my testing to the next level so thank you for that!