# I want to create testcase for my project but i got this error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

this is the testcase i wrote

i have user model that records create only with email confirmation
so i have to get email code from EmailConfirm model and i can't pass it to test class as self.email_code. same problem for self.refresh_token and self.user_id

```
class AccountTestCase(APITestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.email_code = None
    self.refresh_token = None
    self.user_id = None
    
    return super().setUp()

def test_send_email_code(self):
    url = reverse("accounts:resend_code")
    
    data = {
        'email': 'testuser@example.com'
    }
    
    response = self.client.post(url, data)
    
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
    self.email_code = EmailConfirm.objects.get(email='testuser@example.com').code
    

def test_register(self):
    url = reverse("accounts:register")
    
    data = {
        'username': 'testuser',
        'email': 'testuser@example.com',
        'password': 'testpassword',
        'confirm_password': 'testpassword',
        'code': self.email_code
    }
    
    response = self.client.post(url, data)
    
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    
    self.user_id = response.data['id']
    
def test_login(self):
    url = reverse("accounts:login")
    
    data = {
        'username': 'testuser',
        'password': 'testpassword',
    }
    
    response = self.client.post(url, data)
    
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
    self.refresh_token = response.data['refresh']
    
def test_token_refresh(self):
    url = reverse("accounts:token_refresh")
    
    data = {
        'refresh': self.refresh_token
    }
    
    response = self.client.post(url, data)
    
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
    self.access_token = response.data['access']
```

The errors:

ERROR: test_register (accounts.tests.AccountTestCase)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mahdyar Eatemad\OneDrive\Projects\Django\ReelRave API\reelrave\accounts\tests.py", line 40, in test_register
    response = self.client.post(url, data)
  File "C:\Users\Mahdyar Eatemad\OneDrive\Projects\Django\ReelRave API\reelrave\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 296, in post
    response = super().post(
  File "C:\Users\Mahdyar Eatemad\OneDrive\Projects\Django\ReelRave API\reelrave\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 209, in post
    data, content_type = self._encode_data(data, format, content_type)
  File "C:\Users\Mahdyar Eatemad\OneDrive\Projects\Django\ReelRave API\reelrave\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 180, in _encode_data
    ret = renderer.render(data)
  File "C:\Users\Mahdyar Eatemad\OneDrive\Projects\Django\ReelRave API\reelrave\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py", line 913, in render
    return encode_multipart(self.BOUNDARY, data)
  File "C:\Users\Mahdyar Eatemad\OneDrive\Projects\Django\ReelRave API\reelrave\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 261, in encode_multipart
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Cannot encode None for key 'code' as POST data. Did you mean to pass an empty string or omit the value?
```

ERROR: test_token_refresh (accounts.tests.AccountTestCase)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mahdyar Eatemad\OneDrive\Projects\Django\ReelRave API\reelrave\accounts\tests.py", line 67, in test_token_refresh
    response = self.client.post(url, data)
  File "C:\Users\Mahdyar Eatemad\OneDrive\Projects\Django\ReelRave API\reelrave\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 296, in post
    response = super().post(
  File "C:\Users\Mahdyar Eatemad\OneDrive\Projects\Django\ReelRave API\reelrave\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 209, in post
    data, content_type = self._encode_data(data, format, content_type)
  File "C:\Users\Mahdyar Eatemad\OneDrive\Projects\Django\ReelRave API\reelrave\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 180, in _encode_data
    ret = renderer.render(data)
  File "C:\Users\Mahdyar Eatemad\OneDrive\Projects\Django\ReelRave API\reelrave\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py", line 913, in render
    return encode_multipart(self.BOUNDARY, data)
  File "C:\Users\Mahdyar Eatemad\OneDrive\Projects\Django\ReelRave API\reelrave\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 261, in encode_multipart
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Cannot encode None for key 'refresh' as POST data. Did you mean to pass an empty string or omit the value?
```

FAIL: test_login (accounts.tests.AccountTestCase)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mahdyar Eatemad\OneDrive\Projects\Django\ReelRave API\reelrave\accounts\tests.py", line 56, in test_login
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
AssertionError: 400 != 200
```

Comment: This related question should be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76341525/database-not-updating-between-tests-in-django/76341669#76341669